# Skipping records on process

Tags: java, spring-batch

I'm using spring batch to persist the data into DB.
My scenario is I have to skip the records on process if they are fault or error records. For suppose I have 500 records and the commit intervel is 50. If I had a error at the 40th record, then only that record has to be skipped rest of the records should persist into the DB. I have implemented skip mechanism for skipping a file.

this is code where I'm tring to skip. This code is skipping the entire file.

```
<batch:step id="SlavePromotion">
    <batch:tasklet>
        <batch:chunk reader="promotionFileXmlReader" writer="dbPromotionWriter" 
            commit-interval="50" skip-limit="10"> 
           <batch:skippable-exception-classes>
            <batch:include class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileParseException"/>
            <batch:include class="org.springframework.batch.core.step.skip.SkipException"/> 
            <batch:include class="org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException"/>
            <batch:include class="org.springframework.dao.DuplicateKeyException"/> 
            <batch:include class="org.springframework.dao.EmptyResultDataAccessException"/> 
            </batch:skippable-exception-classes>              
        </batch:chunk>              
    </batch:tasklet>
</batch:step>
```

I Have two xml files in the source folder.

```
    file-1
<Root>
  <>Child1</>
  <>Child2</>
  <>Child3</>
</Root>
file-2
<Root>
  <>Child4</>
  <>Child5</>
  <>Child6</>
</Root>
```

I have kept commit interval as "1". When I process the files, reader to writer,my child2 record -of file is duplicate record. So, it should skip the second record and continue with child3.

Comment: The commit is always on a batch level. Spring will either commit the whole batch successfully or fail the whole batch. Your scenario of skipping only one record is not supported in the configuration.

Comment: In our case the entire file is skipping. It is not going to the next batch.

Comment: What is the stack trace you are getting when the job ends?